# AngularJS filters - How can we filter with multiple objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am facing an issue in using angular filters ....

Parent HTML:

`<parent-directive filters="{groupName:'discount'}"></parent-directive>`

Directive Contents:

`<tr ng-repeat="item in collection | filter : $scope.filters"></tr>`

I am filtering with a single object `groupName` in the collection and it is working correctly. Suppose if i need to filter with multiple objects (i.e) `groupName` can be `discounts` or `rewards`. How can i send it to the directive and filter.

Comment: You need to explain what the issue is and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Some HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in person.friends | myFilter">
   {{ friend }}
</li>
```

Make custom filter:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function () {
  return function (items) {
    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      if (item == 'some magic you need to do or compare to') {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

https://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/